# Connect to Prosody XMPP server using Strophe js (CONNFAIL)

Tags: javascript, xmpp, strophe

I have a prosody server setup at example.com. I can connect to the bosh service using pidgin with the url `http://example.com:5280/http-bind` and also on the broswer the same url replies :

> It works! Now point your BOSH client to this URL to connect to
>   Prosody.
>
> For more information see Prosody: Setting up BOSH.

Now i am trying to with using the following command

```
new Strophe.Connection("http://example:5280/http-bind/").connect("admin@example.com", "123456", callback);
```

where callback is a `fuction(status)` I use to log the connection. The status at callback first is **Strophe.CONNECTING** and then **Strophe.CONNFAIL** .

I have enabled the debug log level on prosody and the `/var/log/prosody/prosody.debug` doesn't add new entries (it works fine on pidgin).

Also, I have fixed the proxy by adding the following lines on apache2 virtualhost

```
<Location /http-bind>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/http-bind$ http://example.com:5280/http-bind [P,L]
```

I note that on pidgin I had to enable **plain-text** authentication in order to make it work and also I have the following setting on `/etc/prosody/prosody.cfg.lua` (I have more but these seem related)

```
c2s_require_encryption = false
s2s_secure_auth = false
authentication = "internal_plain"
```

and also the following BOSH settings

```
consider_bosh_secure = true
cross_domain_bosh = true
```

At first, I thought that the problem was the encryption, however, since there are no log entries I am lost. Do you have any idea what the problem maybe, also do you think I should include any more info?

Answer (score 1):

`"http://example:5280/http-bind/"` is not the same URL as `"http://example.com:5280/http-bind"`. You should remove the trailing slash.

Comment: Removing the trailing slash had not effect. However, after debugging a little with firebug I found a warning about CORS request blocked, so I am going to look into that.